# Why is my syntax highlighting not working in my build.gradle file in intellij

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

When I create a build.gradle file and open it with IntelliJ, it does not recognize the build.gradle file and a lightbulb appears suggesting that I correct my gradle syntax. See the picture on top. I can still run the gradle file successfully in intellij.

However, when I create a Gradle Project using the New Project option in IntelliJ, I get proper syntax highlighting.

What should I do to get syntax highlighting for my build.gradle file?

[image: build.gradle syntax highlighting not working in intellij]

Comment: You've clicked "Reload" in your Gradle Tab yeah?

Comment: The gradle tab wasn't available to click on. The accepted answer fixed the problem though, I had to right click on the build.gradle file and choose import gradle project.

Comment: For some reason there's no _Import Gradle Project_ for me in Intellij when I right-click on the file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For an IDE to recognize `build.gradle` files as a Gradle build script instead of simple plain Groovy file it needs to be opened(imported) as a Gradel build file. You can do it from the file's context menu:

[image]